# Как добавить нуль терминированный символ для string\wstring строк?

Tags: c++, windows, c++11

Как корректно добавить нуль терминированный символ для `string\wstring` строк из стандартной библиотеки?

**Задача** - сравнить представление `wstring` строки с вектором из байт, в котором содержится представление этой строки + нуль терминированный символ. Что же делать, вырезать последний байт из вектора?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Туда не нужно добавлять терминатор, т.к. тип (`std::basic_string<CharT>`) хранит данные о длине строки и абстрагирует пользователя от ее внутреннего устройства.